# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in binary tree constructor

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm writing a program that is supposed to demonstrate how binary trees work, it's kinda like 20 questions but it adds new questions on at the end, etc.

I've got most of it down, the code will compile, but it gives me error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" (In Xcode) when I try to execute it.

Here's an excerpt from my main.cpp that initializes the tree:

```
std::string firstSubjectGuess = "rabbit";
tree guessTree(firstSubjectGuess);
```

A top portion of my header file creating the node struct and declaring the constructor/deconstructor:

```
struct node
{
    std::string question;
    std::string subject;
    node *yes = NULL;
    node *no = NULL;
};

class tree
{
public:
    //tree();
    tree(std::string subject);
    ~tree();
```

Then the constructor for the tree class:

```
tree::tree(std::string subject){
    node* root;
    root->yes = NULL;
    root->no = NULL;
    root->question = "Are you thinking of " + getAOrAn(subject[0]) + " " + subject + "?";
    root->subject = subject;
    this->root = root;
    cursor = root;
}
```

In the current state I get the error at the line

```
root->subject = subject;
```

In the class file. However if I change the main.cpp to take the string directly rather than a variable

(I.E.

```
tree guessTree("rabbit");
```

) I get the error at the line

```
    root->yes = NULL;
```

I'm hoping it's something simple that I'm just overlooking, as that's what it usually is.

Comment: Your constructor invokes *undefined behavior*. `root` is indeterminate. It has never been granted a valid node address, and yet you dereference it repeatedly. Unrelated, I strongly advise against naming local automatic variables the same name as members. Yes, you can, but that doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will make sure to switch up the naming of those variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node *root;
```

You declared this pointer, but forgot to actually initialize it with `new`.

Every self-respecting C++ compiler will loudly warn you about using an uninitialized variable. If you received a warning from your compiler, when trying to compile this, take it as a learning experience: never ignore warning from your compiler. The only output you should get when compiling code is: nothing. Only the resulting object file.

Your compiler can't obviously catch every logical bug in your code, but it can catch some of the obvious ones. And if you did not receive a warning from your compiler, read its documentation and figure out which compiler options turns on warning messages.

Comment: Just like I thought, something simple that I feel stupid for overlooking. Thanks for the nice answer! My compiler didn't throw out a warning, otherwise I'm sure I would have caught it. I'll be sure to take your advise and look into it to see if there is some option I can change to allow it to more liberally show warnings. Note: I solved the issue by declaring root as.    node* root = new node;